# Best way of printing simple reports in java

Tags: java, report

I have developed a Java application and now i want to give some simple printing support. Something like printing invoices , some reports etc.
Right now I'm creating that stuff in html, showing it on JEditorPane. but html support is quite poor and I'm really fade up of that thing. Is there any better way of doing such thing?
Any better browser component, or better tool to create such simple reports? (JDK 1.6)

Comment: If you want just a better way of displaying the data you're already collecting you may want to look into Display Tags, it's just a framework for making tables and such. Pretty light and easy to use, though you have to get the data for it yourself, so I'm not sure this is what you're looking for. http://displaytag.sourceforge.net

Comment: Actually I want to design a invoice, put some data which i already have with me in to it and allow user to print it. Thats it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I love [JasperReports](http://jasperforge.org/projects/jasperreports) for that. In combination with iReport (a GUI for creating the reports) is the best I could find for free in Java to do reporting.

You can also generate PDFs files with [iText](http://itextpdf.com/) for printing. Although I think it will be easier to use iReports.

Comment: Thanks! But I think its a bit heavy for me! any alternatives?

Answer (score 3):

[JasperReports](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/) is a pretty nice reporting tool for Java. It could be a bit heavy weight for what you want.

Answer (score 3):

Another solution is [BIRT](http://www.eclipse.org/birt/) which is very simple to use : it is an Eclipse project with a visual editor for your reports. The report is built in 3 steps :

- create a DataSource
- create a DataSet on this DataSource
- create your report, based on the DataSet

Answer (score 3):

[DynamicReports](http://dynamicreports.sourceforge.net/) is an open source reporting tool. You can create reports quickly without needing to use a visual designer. See the [examples](http://dynamicreports.sourceforge.net/examples/examples.html).

Answer (score 3):

When printing invoices and reports, no doubt you want them to look more than basic - hence your problem.  If your swing application has a server-side component, then look at libraries like Jasper and [Docmosis](http://www.docmosis.com) to produce decent reports from the server (since heavy-weight server side is typically aok).  If you really need a library just for a client app, there's an old library called [JViewPro](http://www.hexatech.com/jviewpro.html) which is pretty yuk to code with, but can let you layout reports in code for displaying and printing and is a single jar (just be careful about memory usage).